# Why does Xamarin ListView Cahcing Strategy show "Ambiguous Reference"?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Below is a screenshot of a page in the "core" project. When adding `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`, I receive an

> "Ambiguous Reference" error.

Hovering over it does not give any additional information on how to fix it, neither does ReSharper.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSEt5.png]

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Spent 3~4 days tearing my hair out over it, but no luck.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this with XVS 4.2.1.60 and XF 2.3.2. Can you confirm with those versions?

Comment: Tried a few version of Xamarin, all with the same error. Currently running latest and it still shows the same error.

Comment: Share a .zip of a sample reproducing this. I can't seem to reproduce. Also, please post your full version info from VS, perhaps it's some extension you have like Resharper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify RecycleElement in the ListView constructor instead using x:Arguments

```
<ListView ...>
  <x:Arguments>
    <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
  </x:Arguments>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper is simply unable to see that property because [it does not really exist or at least ReSharper is not able to detect it](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/#Setting_the_Caching_Strategy_in_a_Subclassed_ListView) (read that paragraph for Xamarin saying this). Xamarin Forms does some tricky stuff (I think they use PInvoke or a compiler trick but cannot quite remember), when the code gets compiled, in order to change your `ListView` code when that property is specified and ReSharper is not aware that it is going on. Hopefully ReSharper will fix this in an update though I am not sure if they ever will.

Answer (score 1):

When use the above method shows 
`"Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'CachedListView' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"` is it nesseary to add x:Arguments? or is it nessasary to give reference as

```
xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:TestProject.Data"
```

Comment: I used the above method and got the same error, please let me know if you got it solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add class

```
public class CachedListView : ListView
{
    public CachedListView() : base(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement) { }
}
```

And in Xaml use CachedListView instead ListView.